# Creating three children in C that have the same parent

Tags: c, linux, fork, parent-child

My problem is that the children does not have the same parent and does not appear correctly, here is my code:

```
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
   pid_t pid[3];

   pid[0] = fork();

   if(pid[0] == 0)
   {
   /* First child */
      pid[1] = fork();
      if(pid[1] == 0)
      {
         /* First child continued */
         printf("Hello, I'm the first child! My PID is : %d, My PPID is: %d", getpid(), getppid());
         sleep(1);
       }
       else
       {
          /* Second child */
          pid[2] = fork();

          if(pid[2] == 0)
          {
             /* Second child continued */
             printf("Hello, I'm the second child! My PID is : %d, My PPID is: %d", getpid(), getppid());
             sleep(1);
          }
          else
          {
             /* Third child */
             printf("Hello, I'm the first child! My PID is : %d, My PPID is: %d", getpid(), getppid());
             sleep(1);
           }
       }
   }
   else
   {
   /* Parent */
      sleep(1);
      wait(0);
      printf("Hello, I'm the parent! My PID is : %d, My PPID is: %d", getpid(), getppid());
   }
   return 0;
}
```

As of right now when i run the program i will get this as output in bash, where bash has the PID of 11446:

```
>Hello, I'm the third child! My PID is: 28738, My PPID is: 28735
>Hello, I'm the first child! My PID is: 28742, My PPID is: 28738
>Hello, I'm the second child! My PID is: 28743, My PPID is: 28738
>Hello, I'm the parent! My PID is: 28753, My PPID is: 11446
```

How do i get the first child to appear first, second child to appear second and the third child to appear last, and get all the children to have the PPID 28753

Comment: Apparently, your third child is creating child1 and child2. But the parent does not have the same PID as your childrens' parent.

Comment: Have you heard about a programming construct called loop? It's a neat thing, it allows you to do the same thing several times without copying and pasting code.

Comment: If you fork processes, they run in _parallel_. You cannot except them to output in a particular order without some sort of explicit synchronisation or at least delaying the output of each by a successively larger amount.

Comment: (And if you want all children to have the same parent, then you must fork them all _from_ that parent. The code as written has one child fork another).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From man fork:

> **RETURN VALUE**
>          On success, the PID of the child process is returned in the parent, and 0 is returned in the child.  On failure, -1 is returned in
>   the parent, no child process is created,  and  errno  is  set
>          appropriately.

Your `if`-`else` conditions are swapped.

Comment: @davmac Thanks. Yes, but other things are screwed, like child creates other children. I hope this hint answer can help OP to better visualize correct the code.